# BERT tokenizer mod

Tags: python

I have a cleaned column of sentences in my excel I just wanted to take that particular column into data frame and then put it between the BERT tokenizer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('blah.xlsx')
text = df["text_clean"].astype(str).tolist()
marked_text = "[CLS] " + str(text) + " [SEP]"
marked_text[:10211]
```

I don't get the output CLS and SEP after each sentence.
The output is

```
'[CLS] [\'I think in that case you might want to start stockpiling gin just so you re ready for Season 2 when it hits\', \'Caught up on Dynasties and now need a large gin and some ther...
```

no SEP found at all.
Just to remind the first sentence in the above output is first row followed by the second row and so on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an example of your `blah.xlsx` file.

Comment: Please also read how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your problem does not seem to be related to `pandas` and can be simplified.

Comment: Please provide the **expected output**.

Answer (score 0):

`[SEP]` *is* at the end of the *stringified* list. You can check by printing the 10 last characters of your string with:

```
print(marked_text[-10:])
```

That said, I guess your expected result is

```
[CLS] 'I think in that case you might want to start stockpiling gin just so you re ready for Season 2 when it hits' [ SEP]
[CLS] 'Caught up on Dynasties and now need a large gin and some ther...' [ SEP]
...
```

To do so, apply string concatenation to *each* of your text entries:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('blah.xlsx')
text = df["text_clean"].astype(str).tolist()
marked_text = []
for e in text:
    marked_text.append("[CLS] " + str(e) + " [SEP]")
print(*marked_text)
```

output:

```
[CLS] 'I think in that case you might want to start stockpiling gin just so you re ready for Season 2 when it hits' [ SEP] [CLS] 'Caught up on Dynasties and now need a large gin and some ther...' [ SEP]...
```